# separate array by every four value and make MySql insert

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Sorry I'am new in this.I have a array like this one :

```
array(Jason,bp 9/27,07AAC,Mike,T/L KGL 6,07AAB);  //(could be more or less
```

I need to separate this by every four value. And I would like to make MySql insert like this:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`name` ,`address` ,`number`)
VALUES
  ('Jason', 'bp 9/27', '07AAC'),
  ('Mike', 'T/L KGL 6', '07AAB')
    ..... (could be more or less)
```

I already make a code but it keep show an error and I don't have any idea which part is wrong.

Below is a code that will receive a data from ajax.

```
if ($_POST['action'] == "checktransfertmp") {

   $arrCheckTrans = $_POST['arrCheckTrans'];

   $trans = explode(",", $arrCheckTrans);
   $output = array_chunk( $trans, 4 );
   //print_r($trans);
$addContact = addCheckCustomertemp($output);
        if ($addContact != false) {
            echo "ok.";
        }

}
```

After that it will send the data in a form array_chunk into mysql.

```
function addCheckCustomertemp($output){

    $connection = MySQLConnection();
    $conf = new BBSupervisorConf();

    $flag =true;

    $query  = 'INSERT INTO bb_customer(customername, address, callername) VALUES ';

foreach ($output as $chunk) {

    $query .= '(' . implode( ',', $chunk ) . '),';
}

$query = substr($query, 0, -1);


    try {
    if (!mysql_query($query)){
        die (mysql_error()); 
        $flag = false;
    }else{
}
  }catch(Exception $e){
   //some log here
  }
    closeDB($connection);
    return $flag;
}
```

I keep trying and only result I get is :
*You have an error in your SQL syntax;check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '9/27,07AAC),(Mike, T/L KGL 6' at line 1 .

If this is a silly question or I'm a bad explanantion let me apologize first.Any help or comment will be greatly appreciate.

Comment: If you print the SQL query you get before running it, you will probably see the issue easily (wrong syntax around quotes and parenthesis).

Comment: sorry ,but I dont get it

Comment: After `$query = substr($query, 0, -1);`, add `print $query;` so you can see the string you built there...

Comment: @Galz I already debug my code and it show something like this (string) INSERT INTO bb_customer(customername, address, callername) VALUES ('Jason,bp 9/27,07AAC),(Mike,T/L KGL 6,07AAB) .I think there is no wrong right?

Comment: It is wrong - should be `VALUES ('Jason','bp 9/27','07AAC'),('Mike','T/L KGL 6','07AAB')`. Which means you are missing the single quotes around each value. Find a way to add the quotes before and after each 'chunk'..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing this:

```
$query .= '(' . implode( ',', $chunk ) . '),';
```

with this:

```
$query .= "('" . implode( "','", $chunk ) . "'),";
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
$array= array('Jason','bp 9/27','07AAC','Mike','T/L KGL 6','07AAB');
$cnt= sizeof($array);
$sql = " INSERT INTO `table` (`name` ,`address` ,`number`) VALUES ";
for($i=0;$i<$cnt; $i+=3){
$sql .= "('".$array[$i]."','".$array[$i+1]."','".$array[$i+2]."'),";
}
$sql = substr($sql,0,-1).";";

echo $sql;
exit();
```